# How to detect modified files using Dropbox Core Api on Android?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I'm developping an Android App and I'm using Dropbox Core Api for that purpose. I'm not using Sync Api since I'm interested in having full access permission to my Dropbox account and I've read that's not possible using Sync Api.

So, using Dropbox Core Api, is there any way to know if a file has been modified in order to update it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for an updated `rev` field via a call to `/metadata` or use `/delta` to poll for changes. (Optionally, you can use `/longpoll_delta` to get notified when changes happen.) See details of what the Core API offers here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs.

On Android, these calls are:

- metadata: https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#metadata(java.lang.String, int, java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.String)
- delta: https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#delta(java.lang.String)

`longpoll_delta` isn't included in the SDK, so you'd need to call it directly via HTTP if you want to use it.